# Coordinates where connection coefficients vanish at a point

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

Let $\nabla$ be a connection on a vector bundle $E \to M$, and let $p$ be an arbitrary point on $M$. Does there exist a local frame of $E$ such that the connection coefficients of $\nabla$ with respect to this frame vanish at $p$?

Such coordinates always exist when $\nabla$ is the Levi–Civita connection on a Riemannian manifold, but I haven't seen any information on the general case.

I think this problem can be reduced to solving the following differential equation. Suppose $(e_i)$ is a local frame of $E$ with connection matrix $\theta = (\theta_{ij})$, i.e.
$$
\nabla e_i = \sum_j \theta_{ij}e_j.
$$
If $(e_i')$ is another local frame of $E$ with connection matrix $\theta'$ such that $e_i' = \sum_j g_{ij}e_j$, we have the transformation law
$$
\theta' = dg \cdot g^{-1} + g \cdot \theta \cdot g^{-1}.
$$
Note that each product in this equation is a product of matrices. Thus, in order for $\theta' = 0$, we must solve the differential equation
$$
0 = dg + g \cdot \theta.
$$

Comment: Yes, but you only need to solve the equation at $p$. Write this all in local coordinates $g = g(x^1, \dots, x^n)$, $dg = \partial_ig\,dx^i$, and $\theta = \theta_i\,dx^i$. All you need to do is solve for $\partial_i g(p)$.

Comment: @Deane That's very simple, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out thanks to Deane's comment. The key is that the equation
$$
0 = dg + g \cdot \theta
$$
only needs to hold at $p$. (In fact, by the above argument it admits a solution everywhere iff the connection is flat.) We can take $g_{ij}(p) = \delta_{ij}$, so that this equation becomes
$$
0 = dg(p) + \theta(p).
$$
That is, we need to find $g$ so that its derivatives at the point $p$ are prescribed by the connection matrix $\theta$. It suffices to take $g$ to be linear in some coordinate system.

Comment: Here's the next exercise: Find a quadratic expansion of $g$ that eliminates as many first order terms of $\theta$ as possible. You'll discover the curvature tensor this way.

Comment: @Deane I’ve been working on this exercise, and I don’t think I’m able to eliminate all the first order terms of $\theta$ (though it’s likely I’m making some calculation mistakes). When you say “eliminate as many first order terms as possible,” does that mean that it’s not possible to eliminate all of them?

Comment: That’s right. It’s not possible to eliminate all first order terms. The ones that can’t always be eliminated comprise the components of the curvature tensor. This shows that a connection is flat to first order at a point if and only if the curvature tensor vanishes at that point.

Comment: @Deane Thanks! I think I was able to figure it out; about half the terms go to 0 and the others are all components of the curvature tensor. Do you happen to know if there’s a deeper reason why the curvature terms show up? It seems like I should get a nice formula for the first order expansion of the connection (whatever that means) in terms of the curvature, but I’m not sure. I guess my trouble is that the connection matrix is not quite a tensor.

Comment: If the connection were flat, you would be able to eliminate all of the first coefficients by solving for the “right” frame. But curvature is by definition the first order obstruction to this. So you expect to see the curvature in the terms you can’t eliminate. And since curvature is the only first order obstruction, you expect to see only the curvature in these terms.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot for the insights!